# RadioButton state does not cache on windows 10 UWP

Tags: windows-10, uwp

Even after enabling `NavigationCacheMode`, radio button on the universal app for windows 10 does not cache. I have placed radio button in a list, but after navigating back from the next page, `IsChecked` property for all the radio buttons is shown false.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the scenario you mentioned, and It has correctly cached the radio buttons state.

What I did is a page with `NavigationCacheMode.Required` with a listview of radiobuttons and a button to navigate to another page and then return back.

```
   <ListView>
            <RadioButton Content="Test1"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Test2"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Test3"/>
   </ListView>
```

I think the issue, you might have code in OnNavigatedTo or LoadState method that reinitialize the list again.